# C# How can I change textbox.Text from a static method in a separate class and thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, sockets, static-methods

So the issue I'm having is that i want to set textbox.Text on Form1. I quickly found out about being thread safe and i think the code i have fixes that issue. The next problem i faced was that the way my client is coded the method for setting the text has to be static and i can't think how to do that. Unless of course my client methods within the AsyncClient class don't have to be static, if that's the case and its due to my lack of knowledge that would be great.

I am re-purposing the template from Microsoft for the client as you will likely be able to tell. This is mostly due to the fact i am a University student and am just using it to learn at the minute.

I would also like to apologize in advance if this question already exists, but when i looked i couldn't find anything specific enough to my problem.

This is the top part of the code minus the namespace. I will split it slightly just to focus on the parts i spoke about.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Socket client;

    public delegate void setTextCallback(string text);

    public void setText(string text)
    {
        if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Different thread, use Invoke.
            setTextCallback d = new setTextCallback(FinishSetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            // Same thread, no Invoke.
            this.txtLog.Text = this.txtLog.Text + text;

        }
    }

    private void FinishSetText(string text)
    {
        this.txtLog.Text = this.txtLog.Text + text;
    }
```

Above is the code that as far as errors go fixed the cross treading issue i was having. If there is a better way of doing this I'm up for trying new things.

```
    // State object for receiving data from remote device.  
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.  
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.  
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        // Receive buffer.  
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.  
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    }

    public class AsyncClient
    {
        // The port number for the remote device.  
        private const int port = 8080;

        // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
        private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public struct properties
        {
            public static String response { get; set; }
        }

        public static Socket StartClient()
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to a remote device.  
            try
            {
                // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  

                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

                // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                // Release the socket.  
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

                return client;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                setText(e.ToString()); 
                return client;
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete the connection.  
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                setText(string.Format("Socket connected to {0}",
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

                // Signal that the connection has been made.  
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                setText(e.ToString());
            }
          //Other AsyncClient methods below.
        }
```

Above at the bottom of the code you can see where i am trying to set the text using the method from Form1 but as you can also see the methods are static meaning it expects a static version of that method which means using `This.textbox` doesn't work any longer, or at least this is my understanding of what is happening. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: "the method for setting the text has to be static" - no, surely not.

Comment: I wasn't stating that as fact its just what i assumed was happening, I did post here for help after all.

Comment: Then make the methods of the `AsyncClient` be instance methods and not `static`. Then you have to construct an instance of `AsyncClient` client and then you can pass in an `Action<string> setText` to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` keywords and add this code to the start of your `AsyncClient` class:

```
public class AsyncClient
{
    private Action<string> setText;

    public AsyncClient(Action<string> setText)
    {
        this.setText = setText;
    }
```

Then when you create an instance from your form just do `var ac = new AsyncClient(setText)` and call `ac.StartClient()`.